# How do I integrate Braintree with Magento 1.9.3?

Tags: magento-1.9, braintree

Whic is the best way to integrate Braintree with Magento 1.9.3?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is by using [Braintree Payments module](https://marketplace.magento.com/gene-gene-braintree.html).